# Setting up Win8 ad-hoc Wifi without security?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to set up an ad-hoc wifi network coming from a Windows 8 machine to connect to some legacy hardware that doesn't support WPA. Trouble is, I can't find a way to tell Win8 to start the network without encryption. Is it possible to do so?